# Why byte-addressable memory and not 4-byte-addressable memory?

Tags: memory

Why do computers have byte-addressable memory, and not 4-byte-addressable memory (or 8-byte-addressable memory for 64bit)?  Yeah, I see how it could be useful sometimes, it just seems inelegant and excessive.  Are the advantages substantial, or is it really just because of legacy?

Comment: Basically: Why cut a pizza into 8 slices? Wait what, you cut your pizza into 16 slices!?!?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Processors actually *do* access memory in quantities of 64-bit (x86 did since Pentium or so); 64-bit processors often have a 128-bit bus. Plus, in accessing main memory, you have bursts that fill an entire cache line, which is even larger units of memory.

It's only the addressing that is byte-based; this adds little overhead and is not excessive at all.

Today, you absolutely need byte-based addressing for networking protocols. Implementing TCP with word-based addressing would be difficult: what do you want read() to return if what you received where 17 bytes? Likewise, higher layers are byte-based: HTTP would be fairly difficult to implement if you get a request line like "GET / HTTP/1.0" be presented in units of four bytes. You essentially would have to split the words back into bytes with shift operations and such (which now the processors do in hardware, thanks to byte-based addressing).

Comment: On a word-addressed CPU, the network card could store each network octet into a machine word (and vice-versa for transmit).  Or for the more likely case of packing 4 bytes into 32-bit words (like Alpha AXP, which had no byte-load / byte-store instructions in early versions), your TCP example would return 17, and it would be up to software to deal with the padding in the last word using a shift.  (Alpha was sort of byte-addressable, but it only supported aligned 32 or 64-bit word load/stores, with some hacks for I/O address space.  http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Alpha-HOWTO-8.html)

Comment: Alpha later added byte loads/stores, but it certainly supported TCP (using normal PCI network cards, AFAIK) without them.  That made it effectively a word-addressed machine, but with the low bits of the 64-bit address being ignored (or required to be 0?) instead of not present.

Answer (score 8):

Largely historical reasons - it has become the standard that CPUs understand. [Here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/arithmetic/bits_bytes_2.shtml) is a good discussion on it:

> Generally, a size has to be chosen to
>   be convenient for both data and
>   machine instructions. 8 bits (256
>   values) is enough to accommodate
>   common characters in English and some
>   other languages. Designers of 8-bit
>   processors presumably found that being
>   able to encode 256 common instructions
>   as one byte was a "reasonable
>   tradeoff". And at the time, 8 bits was
>   also generally enough to encode other
>   things such as a pixel colour or
>   screen coordinate. Having a byte size
>   that is a power of 2 may also have
>   been felt to be a "neater" design. It
>   is interesting to note that, for
>   example, Marxer, E. (1974), Elements
>   of Data Processing, describes a byte
>   as being either 6-bit and 8-bit
>   depending on whether the computer was
>   of the "octal" or "hexadecimal" type.

Certainly, other sizes were used in the early days.

Answer (score -1):

We needed to settle down on some size for standardization. People chose 8-bit size for the reasons mentioned by Shane above. since then we are stuck with byte addressable memory. now it is impossible to change due to various compatibility issues and the fact that OPCODES are a byte long only. but using a trick, memory is easily made word-addressable to fetch/store data/addresses!